# How can I filter Salesforce SObjects for mappable objects

Tags: c#, salesforce

I have a C# application which contains objects whose data I want to transfer to Salesforce using the REST API. I would like to allow my users to create a mapping from my application objects to one of their Salesforce objects (e.g. map fields from my applications "Person" object to Salesforce "Contact" object). I want to present the user with a list of objects to choose from and then a list of fields to map for that object.

To do that, I call the Salesforce REST API SOBJECTS endpoint which returns a list of all objects in the user's Salesforce Org. However, this list includes all kinds of objects which would be irrelevant for storing data (e.g. the ApexTrigger object). I want to return only the Salesforce native objects (e.g. Account, Lead) and any custom objects on the user's Salesforce Org.

What fields should I look for to use in my filter? I tried using "custom", but that only returns the custom objects and not the native ones.

Answer (score 0):

For getting only sObjects via Salesforce REST API you need to use next method:

```
https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/
```

See [documentation page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_describeGlobal.htm) for more details.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, this method returns all Salesforce objects, including those which would never be mapped to like "ApexTrigger". I want to return only those objects which the user would map to, like Salesforce native objects and custom objects.

Comment: Hmm.. you are right. Looks like you need to filter response of this call (need to check, are there any fields which can be used for it).